# How to change the SQL query on a Crystal reports locally without access to a customer's database from my machine?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, report

I need to change the SQL query used to pull data from a customer's database on an already existing report but they don't have Crystal Reports installed on their SQL server.

I have a copy of their data on my local machine and can make the change and test it with no problems, but when I upload the report back onto their SQL server, it complains that it can't find the database (unsurprisingly, as I've had to change the connection in the report to use the copy of their data on my machine!)

What I need to know is how I'm able to edit the SQL query used on the report on my machine and have it retain the database connection that's used on the report somehow?

The change I need to make on the report is a bit more complicated than changing links in the database expert in Crystal, its a change to the SQL query used to pull the data from the database.

Thanks, any help is appreciated, I'm fairly new to Crystal Reports so apologies if this is a simple fix.

Comment: Can you post some code. Are you retaining the original connection to remote after making sql changes? or your local connectionstring persist when working with client (this can be the only issue).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the SQL offline if you are using a command. If you are using database expert, you need to connect to the database, which you are already doing. To update database connection on the client computer you can use a tool like this one http://r-tag.com/Pages/CRDataSource.aspx.

Comment: I'm using a command and it asks me to connect. What are the steps to edit/view the SQL command offline?